# Android : Converting color image to grayscale

Tags: android, grayscale

I am trying to convert color image into grayscale using the average of red, green, blue. But it comes out with errors.

**Here is my code**

```
imgWidth = myBitmap.getWidth();
imgHeight = myBitmap.getHeight();
                    
for(int i =0;i<imgWidth;i++) {
    for(int j=0;j<imgHeight;j++) {
     int s = myBitmap.getPixel(i, j)/3;
     myBitmap.setPixel(i, j, s);
    }
}
                    
ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image1);
img.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
```

But when I run my application on Emulator, it's force close. Any idea?

I have solved my problem use the following code:

```
for(int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
            for(int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
                // get one pixel color
                pixel = src.getPixel(x, y);
                // retrieve color of all channels
                A = Color.alpha(pixel);
                R = Color.red(pixel);
                G = Color.green(pixel);
                B = Color.blue(pixel);
                // take conversion up to one single value
                R = G = B = (int)(0.299 * R + 0.587 * G + 0.114 * B);
                // set new pixel color to output bitmap
                bmOut.setPixel(x, y, Color.argb(A, R, G, B));
            }
        }
```

Comment: What's the error post error log.

Comment: Are you getting any exact error in log? such as stackoverflow?

Answer (score 97):

You can do this too :

```
    ColorMatrix matrix = new ColorMatrix();
    matrix.setSaturation(0); 
    imageview.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(matrix));
```

Comment: Is it possible to make it only full-black (0xff000000) and full-white (0xffffffff) ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper You can do that with ImageView's built-in setColorFilter(color, mode) method or a regular PorterDuffColorFilter. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuffColorFilter.html

Comment: @Pkmmte What's the regular PorterDuffColorFilter ?

Comment: This is not working for me. 
I am setting the image in imageview using imageView.setImageBitmap().

Comment: This method is more reliable than converting the image to Bitmap.

Answer (score 33):

Try the solution [from this previous answer by leparlon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3391061/85950):

```
public Bitmap toGrayscale(Bitmap bmpOriginal)
    {        
        int width, height;
        height = bmpOriginal.getHeight();
        width = bmpOriginal.getWidth();    

        Bitmap bmpGrayscale = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(bmpGrayscale);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
        cm.setSaturation(0);
        ColorMatrixColorFilter f = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm);
        paint.setColorFilter(f);
        c.drawBitmap(bmpOriginal, 0, 0, paint);
        return bmpGrayscale;
    }
```

Comment: How can I also lighten the image?  The image is now gray, but it is also dark because of the colors in the original image.

Comment: so after converting it to black and white will image size reduced ? (size in kb)

Comment: Lalit can u tell me how can we extract character from grayscale image?

Comment: Me want dat codez and u answer my question plz!

Comment: Seriously folks, it's usually best to make a new question instead of commenting on an old thread.

Comment: I am trying this in the Android 10 but i get an exception "Software rendering doesn't support hardware bitmaps". Why is that?

Answer (score 15):

Lalit has the most practical answer. *However*, you wanted the resulting grey to be the average of the red, green and blue and should set up your matrix like so:

```
    float oneThird = 1/3f;
    float[] mat = new float[]{
            oneThird, oneThird, oneThird, 0, 0, 
            oneThird, oneThird, oneThird, 0, 0, 
            oneThird, oneThird, oneThird, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 1, 0,};
    ColorMatrixColorFilter filter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(mat);
    paint.setColorFilter(filter);
    c.drawBitmap(original, 0, 0, paint);
```

And finally, as I have faced the problem of converting an image to grayscale before - the most visually pleasing result in all cases is achieved by not taking the average, but through giving each colour different weight depending on its percieved brightness, I tend to use these values:

```
    float[] mat = new float[]{
            0.3f, 0.59f, 0.11f, 0, 0, 
            0.3f, 0.59f, 0.11f, 0, 0, 
            0.3f, 0.59f, 0.11f, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 1, 0,};
```

Comment: @user1324936 care to elaborate?