# How to convert background image to grayscale in android?

Tags: android

I was going through [Android : Converting color image to grayscale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8381514/android-converting-color-image-to-grayscale) and other similar answers, when I doubted whether it's possible to grayscale a coloured "background image" i.e., image set using `android:background=""`. Is it possible? If yes, how?
I have not got the answer even after several hours of extensive googling.

**EDIT**: I have found a hack for the problem, but it does not solve the problem completely. I have used

```
android:backgroundTint="#999999"
android:backgroundTintMode="multiply"
```

along with my code to set the background image.

Comment: no, by using `android:background=...`, it is not possible, but you can use `View#setBackground` method in java code and use a custom `Drawable` class

Answer (score 2):

Use an ImageView in your layout instead of trying to set the background to a drawable and then use this code to programmatically color the image to grayscale.

```
final ColorMatrix matrix = new ColorMatrix();
matrix.setSaturation(0);
final ColorMatrixColorFilter filter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(matrix);
mImageView.setColorFilter(filter);
```

If you need help using an ImageView instead of background, please post your layout xml and java code for this scene.