# How to turn all colorful pixel to gray in drawable or bitmap

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I want to draw a bitmap, but with only gray pixel (for example 0x555555 color).

So I should change all the colorful pixel's color to gray.

How to do this or how to draw an image with only grayed pixels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called "converting image to grayscale in English". Making a simple search I found the following [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373860/convert-a-bitmap-to-grayscale-in-android) (luckily it targets exactly Android. Hopefully it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can read every pixel, convert it to RGB color system.
Then if you want grey, then Red, Green and Blue must have equal value.

I don't know exactly what is best, when you get the good "gray" color.
But maybe if you do this math: (Red + Green + Blue) / 3 = x
Color R = x, G = x, B = x;
Then they all got the same color, but I don't know if yo get a correct gray scale with this.

If you need more information, just say it, I got some code how to read pixels from a bitmap and convert them into RGB color system.

Comment: This is not the best formula for converting to grayscale. The most common formula is: (red*0.3 + green*0.59 + blue*0.11). See here for example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale#Converting_color_to_grayscale