# How do you set the camera to send gray scale images?

Tags: android, android-camera, yuv

The camera in android gives us output in a format called YUV which we have to convert to RGB and then to gray.
I was wondering if there is a way to set the camera so that it sends us gray scale images directly?

Comment: refer [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3391061/2345913)

Comment: That gives you function to convert the frame. I want to know if there is an easier method to set the camera to send grayscale similar to how we set the resolution/fps etc.