# The resolution is changing after bitmap conversion to grayscale

Tags: android, bitmap, resolution, grayscale

I'm having trouble while converting a bitmap from RGB to Grayscale. Before conversion, the image had a **2102 x 932 pixels** and **300 dpi**. After the conversion, the image size remains the same but the resolution scaled down to **96dpi**. The code to convert to grayscale I'm using is from [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373860/convert-a-bitmap-to-grayscale-in-android) by [leparlon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/367342/leparlon):

```
public Bitmap toGrayscale(Bitmap bmpOriginal){        
    int width, height;
    height = bmpOriginal.getHeight();
    width = bmpOriginal.getWidth();    

    Bitmap bmpGrayscale = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(bmpGrayscale);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
    cm.setSaturation(0);
    ColorMatrixColorFilter f = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm);
    paint.setColorFilter(f);
    c.drawBitmap(bmpOriginal, 0, 0, paint);
    return bmpGrayscale;
}
```

Some of you have faced this kind of issue?