# Android ImageButton with disabled UI feel

Tags: android, image

I have an ImageButton which is disabled (non clickable or set as disabled). I want to give an UI feel to the user that it is disabled without using any other image.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You mean you want the Android framework to grey it out or something like that if you disable it?

Comment: I would do it the way Shlublu describes below. Selectors are super easy once you know about that and very useful.

Comment: yea i know this method will work.but the problem is i dont have any resources. cant we do it without using images?

Comment: Nope, you'll have to use a regular stock button.

Comment: Or to make a black & white copy of your image resource and use it as `button_grayed`. It is very easy to do using any image editor.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Unlike a regular `Button`, an `ImageButton` or a `Button` that has an image background is not grayed when disabled. You actually have to use another image or to process it in a way it appears grayed.

Should using another image be ok, you can do this by using a `<selector>` (here associated to a regular `Button` but this amongs to the same):

- `/drawable/my_selector.xml`:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <item android:state_enabled="false"
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_gray" /> ***button_gray is a Drawable image***
      <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_gray" /> 
      <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_red" /> ***button_red is a Drawable image*** 
  </selector>
  ```

Please note that in a selector the logic applies a sequential way, item per item. Here, `button_red` is used all the time but when the button is disabled or being pushed.

- Your `layout.xml`:

  ```
  <Button android:id="@+id/myButton"
          android:background="@drawable/my_selector" ***this is a reference to the selector above ***
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  />
  ```

And should using another image be a problem, other answers (such as @Tronman's or @southerton's) give you ways to programmatically process the image in a way it appears grayed.

Comment: There is another way. See my solution below.

Comment: I found that the order of the <item> element matters in the my_selector. The item of state_enabled="false" must be put first of the default one.

Comment: @DavidCheung Yes, absolutely. The logic applies a sequential way, item per item.

Comment: You can do this programatically so you don't need to provide new images. Check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49162535/1369016

Comment: @Tiago Yes, a very good solution was already posted by Tronman on that respect

Comment: "Please note that in a selector the logic applies a sequential way,..." and my disabled was last item.  Looked for hours.  Thanks!

Answer (score 38):

@Oleg Vaskevich gave a different solution to the problem here: [Disable an ImageButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8196206/disable-an-imagebutton)

His solution allows you to gray-out an `ImageButton` without creating additional images or using a `<selector>`.

```
/**
 * Sets the image button to the given state and grays-out the icon.
 * 
 * @param ctxt The context
 * @param enabled The state of the button
 * @param item The button item to modify
 * @param iconResId The button's icon ID
 */
public static void setImageButtonEnabled(Context ctxt, boolean enabled, 
        ImageButton item, int iconResId) {

    item.setEnabled(enabled);
    Drawable originalIcon = ctxt.getResources().getDrawable(iconResId);
    Drawable icon = enabled ? originalIcon : convertDrawableToGrayScale(originalIcon);
    item.setImageDrawable(icon);
}

/**
 * Mutates and applies a filter that converts the given drawable to a Gray
 * image. This method may be used to simulate the color of disable icons in
 * Honeycomb's ActionBar.
 * 
 * @return a mutated version of the given drawable with a color filter applied.
 */
public static Drawable convertDrawableToGrayScale(Drawable drawable) {
    if (drawable == null) 
        return null;

    Drawable res = drawable.mutate();
    res.setColorFilter(Color.GRAY, Mode.SRC_IN);
    return res;
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer because it addresses the op's requirement of not using other images. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: To make the disabled buttons grayscale instead of just gray, replace `res.setColorFilter(Color.GRAY, Mode.SRC_IN)` with the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4951839/4284627).

Answer (score 16):

I preferred overriding the `setEnabled()` method in the ImageButton to change the image's alpha property accordingly. So when the button is disabled, the image will be partially transparent and more disabled-looking.

```
public class CustomImageButton extends ImageButton {
    //...

    @Override
    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        if(this.isEnabled() != enabled) {
            this.setImageAlpha(enabled ? 0xFF : 0x3F);
        }
        super.setEnabled(enabled);
    }
}
```

Comment: I love this soluton, btw `3F` means 25% opacity (visible): https://stackoverflow.com/a/41121016/3466808.

Answer (score 9):

Elaborating on @tronman answer you can also compose a function that will gray out dynamically loaded drawables (i.e. not from resource, - for example loaded from raw svg files and converted to BitmapDrawables on the fly).

```
/**
 * Sets the specified image buttonto the given state, while modifying or
 * "graying-out" the icon as well
 *
 * @param enabled The state of the menu item
 * @param item The menu item to modify
 * @param originalIcon The drawable
 */
public static void setImageButtonEnabled(Context ctxt, boolean enabled, ImageButton item, Drawable originalIcon) {
    item.setEnabled(enabled);

    Drawable res = originalIcon.mutate();
    if (enabled)
        res.setColorFilter(null);
    else
        res.setColorFilter(Color.GRAY, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
}
```

If you also have a non-transparent drawable on background (set with android:background) refer to selectors [Android: How to Make A Drawable Selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624609/android-how-to-make-a-drawable-selector) to also modify background.

Comment: Missing `item.setImageDrawable(res);` at the end, but yes this method works too

Answer (score 6):

Using setImageAlpha on the ImageButton, this can be done

While Enabling,

```
 ((ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnImageButton1)).setEnabled(true);
 ((ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnImageButton1)).setImageAlpha(0xFF);
```

while disabling,

```
 ((ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnImageButton1)).setEnabled(false);
 ((ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnImageButton1)).setImageAlpha(0x3F);
```

As @SnoopDougg suggested a custom ImageButton class might be a nice idea extending the ImageButton and setting the ImageAlpha inside;  haven't tried yet but.

Answer (score 3):

You can set it to non clickable and also set the alpha to show that feeling that you mention.

Answer (score 3):

Solution using only xml resource files:

```
    <ImageButton
        style="@style/your-style"
        android:tint="@color/but_color"
        android:src="@drawable/button" />
```

and color resource `but_color` (in res/color folder):

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="#888" />
    <item android:color="?android:attr/colorAccent" />
</selector>
```

That is, we set color tint of the button (works fine on each Android version if using AndroidX support library). The tint itself is color-state-list. Set colors as you need, here is grey for disabled state, and accent color from theme for enabled state.
We change only color, and only need one image drawable. But note that entire color of button will be changed.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void setImageButtonEnabled(@NonNull final ImageView imageView,
                                         final boolean enabled) {
    imageView.setEnabled(enabled);
    imageView.setAlpha(enabled ? 1.0f : 0.3f);

    final Drawable originalIcon = imageView.getDrawable();
    final Drawable icon = enabled ? originalIcon : convertDrawableToGrayScale(originalIcon);
    imageView.setImageDrawable(icon);
}

private static Drawable convertDrawableToGrayScale(@NonNull Drawable drawable) {
    final ColorMatrix matrix = new ColorMatrix();
    matrix.setSaturation(0);
    final ColorMatrixColorFilter filter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(matrix);

    final Drawable mutated = drawable.mutate();
    mutated.setColorFilter(filter);

    return mutated;
}
```

If you use Kotlin, you can create an Extension Function instead, so it looks more elegant:

```
fun ImageView.setImageButtonEnabled(enabled: Boolean){
   //Above implementation here
}
```

and call it using:

```
yourImageView.setImageButtonEnabled(true/false)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin you can utilize Extension functions.

```
fun ImageButton.enable() {
    this.isEnabled = true
    this.imageAlpha = 0xFF
}

fun ImageButton.disable() {
    this.isEnabled = false
    this.imageAlpha = 0x3F
}

myButton.enable()
myButton.disable()
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin extension function to enable/disable an ImageView/ImageButton without IconResId

```
fun ImageView.setImageViewEnabled(enabled: Boolean) = if(enabled) {
    drawable.clearColorFilter()
    isEnabled = true
} else {
    drawable.colorFilter = PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.GRAY, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
    isEnabled = false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're stuck in appcompat land and can't switch to Material Design Components, use a regular `Button`, set a `android:drawableStart`, and set `android:text` to the empty string.

You can create your pressed / disabled / etc. states using a state list and set it as the background the same way you do for a standard button.

If you want the icon to change based on the state, you can also create another state list drawable, and set that into `android:drawableStart`.

You may need to set the min width, and height to 0 to allow the button to contract to the width of a smaller icon.

Set the drawable padding to 0.

```
      <Button
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:minWidth="0dp"
          android:minHeight="0dp"
          android:drawableStart="0dp" 
          android:background="@drawable/button_background"
          android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_add" 
          android:text="" />
```

Answer (score -2):

Nope, your image is the *differentiating* factor.. so if you don't want to change the image then you *cannot* tell whether the image button is disabled, enabled, pressed.