# Is there a way I can gray out an ImageButton in Android without maintaining a separate gray copy of the original Image?

Tags: java, android, css, grayscale, android-imagebutton

I am trying to have an `ImageButton` that **initially has a gray effect** on it & turns into its **original color when selected**. I'm trying to achieve something like [image: this]. I know this can be done in CSS, but was wondering if any Android attribute / function equivalent to it existed.

I read a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228985/android-imagebutton-with-disabled-ui-feel) that seems to suggest that I have to maintain a different gray copy of the same Image in order to achieve this. But it would consume a lot of memory to maintain 2 copies of the same Image if I have, lets say 100+ ImageButtons.

> Unlike a regular Button, an ImageButton or a Button that has an image
>   background is not grayed when disabled. You actually have to use
>   another image or to process it in a way it appears grayed.

So is there really no way to achieve in Android what could be achieved using grayscale in CSS?

Thank You for your time!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using `.png` images, you could use the `ImageView` color filter attribute.

```
public void setDisabled(ImageView imageView) {
    final ColorMatrix grayscaleMatrix = new ColorMatrix();
    grayscaleMatrix.setSaturation(0);
    imageView.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(grayscaleMatrix));
}
```

Comment: Well, that does do what I want, but was wondering if the same could be applied to an `ImageButton` & if yes, how. I want the button itself to gray out when clicked.

Comment: `ImageButton` extends `ImageView`, so the same code should be applicable.

Answer (score 3):

I know I might be very late, but there's also another option to this - I came across the same situation which I tried to solve and found some straightforward alternative.

Specifically for ImageButton I have used `setAlpha(floatValue);`

**Example:**

```
private ImageButton btnPlay;
[...]
btnPlay.setAlpha(0.5f);
```

Another method for setting Alpha effect for ImageView (technically speaking also to ImageButton, which extends ImageView) is `setImageAlpha(inValue between 0 and 255)` - but for me it did not work also for the ImageButton.

---

A downside of this approach could be though that it is not an actual "gray-out". By setting the transparency, you might be at risk if the background behind the button is a texture or an image. This solution works best with plain backgrounds, like black, dark, white, gray etc. that will also help create the "gray-out" feel.

Thanks for the comments that helped figure out this downside.

Comment: Not bad, but this sets the transparency and does not gray out the image.

Comment: Indeed, you are right - in the context I have used it, with black background or something white, it looked neat (like a gray-out effect). However looking back to setting alpha value, I can see a major downside if, for example, the background behind the button is a texture or image. I will edit the response adding this note of the possible downside.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative! I've decided to use it as a 'solution' for the same problem.