# Grayscale PictureDrawable

Tags: android, svg

To grayscale a drawable I do:

```
ColorMatrix matrix = new ColorMatrix();
matrix.setSaturation(200);
ColorMatrixColorFilter filter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(matrix);
drawable.setColorFilter(filter);
```

as [Justin said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793338/drawable-grayscale). It works fine.

I'm using svg-android library. So I'm trying:

```
PictureDrawable pictureDrawable = svg.createPictureDrawable();
ColorMatrix matrix = new ColorMatrix();
matrix.setSaturation(200);
ColorMatrixColorFilter filter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(matrix);
pictureDrawable.setColorFilter(filter);
imageView.setImageDrawable(pictureDrawable);
```

But nothing happens... What is wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid I found the cause in Android source codes:

Drawable.java

```
public abstract void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf);
```

PictureDrawable.java

```
@Override
public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter colorFilter) {}
```

Simply put, any call to `setColorFilter` is useless for `PictureDrawable`s.

Comment: See also my related question and the discussion in the comments:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13655917/how-do-i-tint-this-picturedrawable

Answer (score 1):

I just found this page by googling. In case anyone is still interested i'm using some workaround for the same problem:

```
Picture pic = svg.getPicture();
Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(pic.getWidth(), pic.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
Canvas c = new Canvas(bm);
c.drawPicture(pic, new Rect(0,0,pic.getWidth(), pic.getHeight()));
c.save();
BitmapDrawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bm);
drawable.setColorFilter(getBlackAndWhiteFilter());
imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

instead of using pic.getWidth() and pic.getWidth() you can of course use your preferred imagesize - so the bitmap doesnt get drawn too big since that might cost some performance.