# Set opacity to PictureDrawable

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-drawable, androidsvg

I need a piece of advice with setting opacity to a `PictureDrawable` object since usual `setAlpha()` is not implemented in `PictureDrawable`.
My case is pretty similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13655917/how-do-i-tint-this-picturedrawable) (I also get my drawables from SVGs in raw resources using a library). But I cannot use the solution because I would like to change the opacity dynamically (not by applying color filter at creation).

The context is animating multiple drawables when drawing on a `SurfaceView`.

What could be a good workaround in this situation?

Thank you.

Comment: use Canvas.saveLayerAlpha, this method is used in pre v4 devices when drawing AlphaAnimations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit goes to @pskink, I'll just elaborate it a little for further references.
This is what I do in `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` method (in my case `int opacity` changes iteratively from 0 to 255):

```
int width = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
int height = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();

canvas.saveLayerAlpha(x, y, x + width, y + height, opacity,
                                  Canvas.HAS_ALPHA_LAYER_SAVE_FLAG);

drawable.setBounds(x, y, x + width, y + height);
drawable.draw(canvas);
canvas.restore();
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20342279/4096987) also provides good guidance on `saveLayerAlpha()` usage.