# How to apply a color filter to a view with all children

Tags: android, view, colors, filter

How do I grey out a view uniformly which contains many different items - ImageViews, TextViews, background image. Do I have to grey out each thing individually? Or is there a way to apply the same color filter to all?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Unless somebody else has a better answer, my current method is greying out each item separatedly.

```
PorterDuffColorFilter greyFilter = new PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.GRAY, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
myLayout.getBackground().setColorFilter(greyFilter);
myImageView.setColorFilter(greyFilter);
myTextView.setTextColor(0xff777777);
```

For more or nested children probably a loop with instanceof would be suitable but I don't need it.

Edit: This filter isn't actually grey, a better filter is here: [Drawable => grayscale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793338/drawable-grayscale)
Which can be used in the same way.

Comment: `myLayout.getBackground().setColorFilter(greyFilter);` I was searching it. Great stuff.

Comment: I think the Sam Lu ansewr is the most accurate

Comment: For drawable, you might want to use `drawable.mutate()` to make sure the consistency of your color. Because the color will be cached by default by android framework and make the state of the same drawable shared across application. For example if you use a drawable in `MainActivity`, then set color filter to it. When you use the same drawable in `DetailActivity`, the filter will automatically applied to the drawable in `DetailActivity` since it is cached.

Answer (score 16):

It's easy to do that by defining a custom view group as follows:

```
public class MyViewContainer extends XXXLayout {
    //XXLayout could be LinearLayout, RelativeLayout or others
    private Paint m_paint;

    //define constructors here and call _Init() at the end of constructor function

    private void
    _Init()
    {
        ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
        cm.setSaturation(0);
        m_paint = new Paint();
        m_paint.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm));
    }

    @Override protected void 
    dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        canvas.saveLayer(null, m_paint, Canvas.ALL_SAVE_FLAG);
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }
}
```

All children views of MyViewContainer will be shown in grey. :-)

Comment: This works like a charm. You can play with the ColorMatrix to achieve results you want.

Answer (score 12):

Sam Lu's answer is a good start, but I had performance problems and decided to switch to hardware layers. With hardware layers, you can do it like this:

```
private final Paint grayscalePaint = new Paint();

ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
cm.setSaturation(0);        
grayscalePaint.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm));

public void setGrayedOut(boolean grayedOut) {       
    if (grayedOut) {
        setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, grayscalePaint);
    } else {
        setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_NONE, null);       
    }       
}
```

Be careful not to do the layers in `dispatchDraw()` itself as that will crash the app.

Comment: simply switching to LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE  will cause `"W/OpenGLRenderer: Layer exceeds max. dimensions supported by the GPU (1088x4288, max=4096x4096)"`  crash on big views. And `"max=4096x4096"` depends on the phone model

Answer (score 7):

It depends entirely on the method you are using to "gray out" items. If you are doing so by calling `setEnabled(false)` on the parent `ViewGroup`, by default state flags (like disabled) do not trickle down to the child views. However, there are two simple ways you can customize this:

One option is to **add the attribute** `android:duplicateParentState="true"` to each child view in your XML.  This will tell the children to get their state flags from the parent.  This will mirror ALL flags however, including pressed, checked, etc...not just enabled.

Another option is to **create a custom subclass** of your `ViewGroup` and override `setEnabled()` to call all the child views as well, i.e.

```
@Override
public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    super.setEnabled(enabled);

    for(int i=0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
        getChildAt(i).setEnabled(enabled);
    }
}
```

Comment: No, no, not disable. Grey out (color!)

Answer (score 0):

What I like to do is create a view which overlaps the view you are trying to tint and set its background to a transparent color. Then you can turn the tint on and off by setting that views visibility

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ViewYouWantToTint
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/disabled_tint_overlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/darkTint"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Then in your controller:

```
m_DisabledBlackTintOverlay = (View) view.findViewById(R.id.login_disabled_black_tint_overlay);

m_DisabledBlackTintOverlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to do is fade out or lighten the View colors the solution can be

```
View.setAlpha(@FloatRange(from=0.0, to=1.0) float alpha)
```

Which changes the transparency of the entire view